# How to pass 3rd arg to diff which is a call to another program with multiple arguments?

Tags: command-line, bash, diff

I want to use `diff` to compare a text file with the output of a program.

I realise I can redirect the output of the program to a file and then compare 2 files but was wondering if it is possible to do it like this:

```
diff file1.txt ./myprog 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` (and similar shells that support it) you can use [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Process_Substitution)

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz
```

then

```
$ diff file <(sed 2d file)
2d1
< bar
```

In this case, the program is `sed` and the arguments are `2d` and `file`

---

In shells that don't support process substitution, since `diff` accepts standard input you could do `./myprog 1 2 3 | diff file1.txt -`

Comment: Does the - after file1.txt mean output of pipe goes here?

Comment: @arcomber yes, see `man diff`: *If  a  `FILE` is  `-',  read standard input.*